# Windows, Apache and MSSQL Authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, sql-server, windows-vista, perl

I have a create database script written in perl. I remember it working just fine another machine.  A couple years later using a Vista machine I am trying to use it again and it keeps failing.

The main difference is that now I am using Apache instead of IIS.  In the script the `IUSR` account is granted permissions as it needs to write to the database as a part of another program.  IIS has been uninstalled on this machine but the `IUSR` account still exists.

The `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR` is also seen in the logins drop down in MSSQL(2012).  The machine is running Vista Home Edition. However when running the script I get errors that say that `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR` cannot be found.

I tried also with `COMPUTERNAME\IUSR` just for the heck of it and of course it was not found.  I also tried with `IUSR` alone and for some reason the user isn't being "found"?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer.  Apache runs under the SYSTEM account and I had to change from IUSR to it and it worked fine.